# Using OR statement in R

Tags: r, subset, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
COL1    COL2    
 5       3
 3       10
 4       5
 15      6
```

I subset the dataframe by choosing "Values in COL1 OR COL2 greater than 7"

I tried this:

```
|
```

for my `OR` statement.

Instead of taking the values, it took the entire column and not the rows. I want an answer that looks like this:

```
 COL1    COL2    
 3       10
 15      6
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual code that you used?

Comment: Do you want only the 3 and 15 of the first column?

Comment: `df[df$COL1>7 | df$COL2>7,]`

Comment: @A.Webb your right, I literally just tried that before you posted this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try in base:

```
subset(dat, COL1 > 7 | COL2 > 7)
```

Or the dplyr version:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% filter( COL1 >7 | COL2 > 7)
```